# why does the lockscreen button get pressed twice on kitkat

Tags: java, android, mediasession

The `mediasession` works pretty good for androids greater than or equal to `lollipop` but for some reason, implementing the lockscreen buttons using the mediasession seems to cause problems, I have a handle intent method in my service:

```
private void handleIntentActions(Intent actionIntent) {
        if(actionIntent == null || actionIntent.getAction() == null)return;

        String actionString = actionIntent.getAction();
        if( actionString.equalsIgnoreCase( ACTION_PPLAY ) || actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PLAY)){
            mMediaSessionTransportControls.play();
        }else if( actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PAUSE) ){
            mMediaSessionTransportControls.pause();
        }else if( actionString.equalsIgnoreCase( ACTION_PREVIOUS ) ){
            mMediaSessionTransportControls.skipToPrevious();
        }else if( actionString.equalsIgnoreCase( ACTION_NEXT ) ){
            mMediaSessionTransportControls.skipToNext();
        }else if( actionString.equalsIgnoreCase( ACTION_DISMISS ) ){
            mMediaSessionTransportControls.stop();
        }else if( actionString.equalsIgnoreCase( ACTION_START_FOREGROUND ) ){
            createNotificationChannel();
            requestAudioFocus();
            Log.e("NotifBuildTest", "NotifBUilderBefore: "+notificationBuilder);
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
            Log.e("NotifBuildTest", "NotifBUilderAfter: "+notificationBuilder);
            notification.flags = NotificationCompat.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT|NotificationCompat.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE
                                | NotificationCompat.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | NotificationCompat.FLAG_HIGH_PRIORITY;
            startForeground(APP_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }
```

the `onStartCommand` method looks like this:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(mService, "foreground onStartCommand executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        handleIntentActions(intent);
        updateMetaData("Unknown", "Unknown");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

The `updateMetaData` looks like this:

```
private void updateMetaData(Bitmap albumArt,String songTitle, String artistName){
        mMediaSession.setMetadata( new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, albumArt )
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, artistName )
                .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, songTitle )
                .build() );


PlaybackStateCompat mnew =  PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP )
            .setState(
                      ( getCurrentPlaybackStateCompat(),
                     0,
                     1.0f )
            .build();        
}
```

The `initMediaSession` is like this:

```
public void initMediaSession() throws RemoteException {
        requestAudioFocus();

        //ComponentName mRemoteControlResponder = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), MediaButtonReceiver.class.getName());
        //final Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        //mediaButtonIntent.setComponent(mRemoteControlResponder);

        if(mMediaSessionManager != null)return;

        mMediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), mMediaSessionTag);
        mMediaSessionManager = MediaSessionManager.getSessionManager(mService);
        mMediaSessionTransportControls = mMediaSession.getController().getTransportControls();
        mMediaSession.setActive(true);
        //following flags are now set by default;
        //mMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS |
        //                       MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS);

        updateMetaData("Unknown", "Unknown");

        //setCallbacks
        mMediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {


            @Override
            public void onPlay() {
                //super.onPlay();
                mService.playEvent();
                Toast.makeText(mService.this, "transport play is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateMetaDataWithCurrentStateDetails();
            }


            @Override
            public void onPause() {
                //super.onPause();
                mService.pauseEvent();
                Toast.makeText(mService.this, "transport pause is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateMetaDataWithCurrentStateDetails();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSkipToNext() {
                super.onSkipToNext();
                mService.nextPreviousTrigger(true,true);
                updateMetaDataWithCurrentStateDetails();
            }


            @Override
            public void onSkipToPrevious() {
                super.onSkipToPrevious();
                mService.nextPreviousTrigger(false,true);
                updateMetaDataWithCurrentStateDetails();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStop() {
                super.onStop(); //stop the service                       //BOTH METHODS ARE DIFFERENT
                removeNotification(); //remove the notification UI
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
        mMediaSession.setActive(true);

    }
```

When I click the `play` button in the notification, it works as expected, but when I click the lockscreen's playbutton once, it get's clicked twice,

The `mediaButtonReceiver` I have looks like this(very simple implementation for now):

```
import androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver;

    public class medButtonReceiver extends MediaButtonReceiver {
        public static  int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent mainIntent = null;
            if(count++ % 2 ==0) {
                mainIntent = new Intent(context, mService.class);
                mainIntent.setAction(mService.ACTION_PLAY);
            }else{
                mainIntent = new Intent(context, mService.class);
                mainIntent.setAction(mService.ACTION_PAUSE);
            }
    
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(mainIntent);
            } else {
                context.startService(mainIntent);
            }
    
    
            Log.e( "xTvM::","medButtonReceiver invoked" );
    
        }
    }
```

and the `logcat` run looks like this:

```
/com.app.www E/xTvM::: something to click
09-19 09:55:37.608 8422-8422/com.app.www E/PBS::: Current playback state compat: play
09-19 09:55:37.658 8422-8422/com.app.www E/PBS::: Current playback state compat: pause
09-19 09:55:37.668 8422-8422/com.app.www E/PBS::: Current playback state compat: pause
09-19 09:55:37.678 8422-8422/com.app.www E/xTvM::: something to click
09-19 09:55:37.708 8422-8422/com.app.www E/PBS::: Current playback state compat: pause
09-19 09:55:37.778 8422-8422/com.app.www E/PBS::: Current playback state compat: play
09-19 09:55:37.788 8422-8422/com.app.www E/PBS::: Current playback state compat: play
09-19 09:55:37.808 778-778/? E/KeyguardHostView: ensureTransportPresentOrRemoved = 2
09-19 09:55:37.829 778-778/? E/KeyguardHostView: ensureTransportPresentOrRemoved = 2
09-19 09:55:47.628 618-790/? E/lights: write_int failed to open -1
09-19 09:56:00.891 618-875/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 70
```

which shows that it is actually running twice, but I don't know why. Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not be extending `MediaButtonReceiver` at all - it handles all of the correct logic for you already if you follow [the documentation on the class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver)

Comment: @ianhanniballake , but, if I then android says MediaButtonReceiver cannot be null, how do I fix that?

Comment: @ianhanniballake , I've tried doing this:` <receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>` in the manifest and when I click lockscreen buttons, it gives me a mediaButtonReceiver cannot be null

Comment: @ianhanniballake , java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find any Service that handles android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON or implements a media browser service. is the exact error I get in the logcat

Comment: Did you [follow the documentation on the class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver#service-handling-action_media_button)? It specifically covers exactly what you need to do to avoid that error message.

Comment: @ianhanniballake,  does the service have to extend/implement MediaBrowserService?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, adding that fixed it flawlessly, thanks a tonne for the pointer. :-)

Comment: @ianhanniballake , BTW, do you know why the updateMediaSession() does not update the notification? Do we have to manually pass an intent to the `notificationMangaer`? using `notificationManager.notify(...)`?